# WD MyBook Duo on Linux Issue

Tags: 20.04, external-hdd

External device isn’t showing/mounting on Ubuntu 20.04. How can I fix this?

Output from `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1058:25f6 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. ASM107U3
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1058:25f9 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. ASM107U3
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1058:25f8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. ASM107U2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There is only one WD device plugged in so I'm not sure why it's showing multiple. This is also the case in the next output.

output from `dmesg | tail -30` is

```
$ dmesg | tail -30
[  675.668866] usb 4-1.3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  675.668867] usb 4-1.3: SerialNumber: 575542533239323630313037
[  675.698802] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_sense_invalidCDB (err -2)
[  675.698839] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_adjust_quirks (err -2)
[ 1567.498350] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1567.994387] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1567.994391] usb 4-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1573.150465] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1573.299839] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25f8, bcdDevice=10.02
[ 1573.299842] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[ 1573.299845] usb 1-3: Product: ASM107U2
[ 1573.299847] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: WD
[ 1573.300662] hub 1-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1573.300811] hub 1-3:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 1573.426538] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1573.447766] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25f9, bcdDevice=10.02
[ 1573.447770] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[ 1573.447773] usb 2-3: Product: ASM107U3
[ 1573.447775] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: WD
[ 1573.448891] hub 2-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1573.449061] hub 2-3:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 1573.602477] usb 1-3.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1574.366579] usb 2-3.3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1574.387209] usb 2-3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25f6, bcdDevice=10.09
[ 1574.387213] usb 2-3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 1574.387215] usb 2-3.3: Product: My Book Duo 25F6
[ 1574.387217] usb 2-3.3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 1574.387219] usb 2-3.3: SerialNumber: 575542533239323630313037
[ 1574.408002] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_sense_invalidCDB (err -2)
[ 1574.408039] uas: Unknown symbol usb_stor_adjust_quirks (err -2)
```

This drive has been used on Windows so I guess that could be an issue. There are no security things set up on it that I am aware of and I am using their software. I cannot see a way to turn off anything security related.

I'm a rookie with Linux systems and struggling through old posts to decipher why my external device isn't working. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing to mount the volume? What file system does it use? Do you always use the disk with Windows? You need to disable "Fast Startup" in Windows if you want to share volumes between the two operating systems, otherwise Windows will lock the drive since Fast Startup is actually a hybrid suspend.  Did you do that?

Comment: windows fast start is disabled. Using ```sudo fdisk -l``` the external drive is not showing so i cannot actually mount the drive

Comment: Does the drive appear in the "Disks" application?

Comment: No it doesn’t show there either

Comment: And when is the last time you've tested and confirmed that the device is working on another device or operating system?

Comment: Today. It boots up and can be accessed by windows machines

Comment: For what is worth, WD shows as three devices even when it's all working perfectly.